# Debugging python script with IDE

Tags: python, debugging

I have a python script with some command line options but prior to that, I run a `source` command to set some variables. That is

```
source file.rc
./run_python_script.py -A 1 -B 2
```

I want to interactively debug the python code line by line with an IDE. As I tried PyCharm, I wasn't able to use that in this way. If that is not good for this work, is there any other way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a debug configuration with your options and launch it that way. More on that [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly)

Comment: In the configuration page, I can enter python script and options. For the source command, I see "Before launch: Activate tool window" and I select "Run external tool". However, when I put `source` in front of the "Program" and `file.rc` in front of the "Arguments, I get the error that "source program is not recognized".

Comment: @mahmood see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-third-party-tools.html

Comment: Problem is that `source` command is a shell internal and it is not a program like `ls` or `grep`. I didn't find information on how to use source command in the reference link.